# Get a phone number from contacts

Tags: android, string, contacts

I have a button that I click and that shows contacts. It displays the name, but not the number of a selected contact...

```
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri contactData = data.getData();
            Cursor c = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                contactName.setText(name);

                Something here !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

                contactName.setText(number);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It String the NAME but how can I get the phone number?

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);
        while (phones.moveToNext())
        {
            String name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String number=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

            contactName.setText(name);
            contactNumber.setText(number);
        }
    }
```

With this code it opens my contacts. I touch one, but it always display the LAST name and number that I have added to contacts.

For example, I touch *Adrian (22222222)* and it shows Paul *(33333333)* which is the last person that I have added.

What should I do?

Comment: What all the permissions you mentioned in manifest.xml.

Comment: Permisions to write contacts, read contacts and internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String phoneNumber = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

Comment: 09-03 01:29:57.884  18258-18258/com.example.gpshelp E/CursorWindow: Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 1 rows, 47 columns.
09-03 01:29:57.886  18258-18258/com.example.gpshelp W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40e391f8)
09-03 01:29:57.919  18258-18258/com.example.gpshelp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Comment: Not sure how your cursor is generated. I tried like this
Cursor cntcts = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
    null, null);

Comment: Something similar like yours
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695566/android-api-get-mobile-number-from-contacts?rq=1

Comment: I have solved it, i check a lot of threads in stackoverflow and I found one that helped me. Thank you anyway.